# Element wise multiplication of nested lists

Tags: python, list

I have nested lists of equal length within a list of length *N*:

```
[[13, 12, 12, 66], [13, 12, 66, 12], [13, 66, 12, 12], [78, 12, 12, 12], ...]
```

The result should be an element-wise product of all the lists within the list:

```
[171366, 114048, 114048, 114048, ...]
```

One possible solution I can think of is using a for loop with `np.multiply(list[index], list[index + 1])` but this causes the index to go out of range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math.prod can be used like (where L is the list of lists):

```
from math import prod
M = [prod(x) for x in zip(*L)]

[171366, 114048, 114048, 114048]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `numpy.prod`:

```
l = [[13, 12, 12, 66], [13, 12, 66, 12], [13, 66, 12, 12], [78, 12, 12, 12]]
np.prod(l, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([171366, 114048, 114048, 114048])
```